# iphone sdk: How to get rid of the action sheet in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, uiactionsheet, pressed

I have a UIWebView and when I press a textual link (for at least a second) some kind of UIActionSheet appears with 3 buttons (open, copy and cancel) - Is there a way to prevent it from appearing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using CSS:

```
* {
   -webkit-touch-callout:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently no. In the documentation, neither UIWebView nor UIWebViewDelegate expose some method or property to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
  {
     [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];
  }
```